# 'По окончании этапа' или 'по окончанию этапа'

Tags: выражения, морфология

Как правильно? В коммерческом предложении компании стоит пункт:

> - По окочанию этапа: будет разработан веб сайт компании и разработан фирменный стиль.
> - По окочании этапа: будет разработан веб сайт компании и разработан фирменный стиль.

Comment: Кроме того:
двоеточие не нужно, а _веб-сайт_ - через дефис.

Comment: @AviGordon Двоеточие может быть уместно, если там идёт перечисление. До начала этапа: ...... В первой половине этапа: ...... И т.д.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данном контексте (в значении "после окончания этапа") правильно: **по окочании**.
Подробнее: [ссылка1](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/kak-pishetsya-po-okonchanii-ili-po-okonchaniyu.html), [ссылка2](https://kak-pravilno.net/po-okonchanii-ili-po-okonchaniyu-kak-pravilno/).

> По окончани**и** — если мы говорим в контексте «после какого-либо события», тогда в конце слова пишется буква «и».
>   По окончани**ю** — если предложение строится в контексте «по признаку», тогда в конце слова пишется буква «ю».

Answer (score 1):

Дело, конечно, не в буквах, а в том, что такие конструкции (сделать А после В) требуют предложного падежа.

Сделать А -- *по прибытии, по рассмотрении, по прошествии, по окончании, по получении, по прочтении* и т.д. То есть, "по ком? по чём?"

Знаменательно, что предложным падежом традиционно управляет также глагол "скучать". По ком. Скучать *по матери, по отце, по деде, по сыне, по вас* и т.д. Но это управление, к сожалению, сегодня практически полностью заместилось дательным падежом.